# sitecore permission on the visibility of the Alias ribbon menu

Tags: security, permissions, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to find what is the permission security for allowing visibility of the Alias function in the Presentation tab ribbon.

For the user in question i've browsed to the core database, and under Access viewer, i'm looking that all the items under Applications/Content Editor have read-enabled permissions, specifically the item `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Strips/Presentation/Page Urls` as well as `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Page Urls` are read-enabled

However, when login as this user there is no presentation tab.

I've tried resetting the cache and still nothing changes. I'm using sitecore 6.5.0

Comment: If you have changed permissions recently then you'll need to clear the site cache or do an IIS reset for Access Viewer to truly show you what the users permissions are. Otherwise it will just return the cache of security settings.

Comment: @MangoPieFace, i went to sitecore/admin/cache.aspx, reset the cache, and then went back to access viewer for the user, all the content editor items , including presentation and subitems still show have read rights (all the other permissions are disabled, write, create, rename, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are almost there, but you still need to give the user sufficient access to the /sitecore/system/Aliases item.

1. Create a new role(or use an existent one), for example sitecore\Sitecore Client Aliases. Use this role to add the following permissions.
2. Switch to the Core database and allow Read permission for the /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Page Urls item and its descendants
3. Switch to the Master database and unprotect the /sitecore/system/Aliases item by using the Unprotect Item checkbox in the Configuration tab.
4. Allow Read, Write, Create permissions for the /sitecore/system/Aliases item and Read, Write, Create, Delete permissions for its descendants.
5. Protect the /sitecore/system/Aliases item back.
6. Add user to the sitecore\Sitecore Client Aliases role.

Found here: http://wiki.evident.nl/Sitecore%20alias%20role.ashx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to enable the presentation tab is to use a sitecore standard role.
I'm not totaly sure but i asume it was `sitecore\Sitecore Client Designing`.

And as far as i know you have to use those standard roles to enable access to certain chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Access Viewer for the user which doesn't see the Alias Tab. You can manually switch to the core database and then click on the different tabs with the specified user / role to see what causes this behavior. Most of the times you will find out that some role / restriction was set to a higher level item dat denies read rights.

Comment: i've check both under ribbons/strips and ribbons/chunks and they have all read-enabled, but still the Alias thingie nor the presentation tab show up